# Mapbox tiles API gives 403

Tags: javascript, mapbox, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I'm receiving a 403 error when requesting data from the [Mapbox static tiles API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-tiles/). This API call has been working fine until recently, and we haven't made any changes to our web server configuration, nor our URL policy.

We are accessing via a web page on one of the whitelisted domains, not a tool/CLI.

A 403 suggests that the issue is some kind of access issue. I tried removing the URL policy for the access token in question (to allow access from *any* domain), and this seemed to work - the API calls started succeeding again. So I think the problem only concerns tokens scoped to specific URLs/domains.

Here's an example of the 403 response headers I'm seeing;

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 23
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
Date Tue, 28 Sep 2021 15:41:04 GMT
ETag W/"17-bqIm6pxC4cx+ZoszvXxsClwgWw8"
Via 1.1 572270b8624c0596173ef8189682d917.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id pxwf39dmi1zB3oFY9dvYia_dVZpcgKpYCTDJT5Vjfp85MsU8NuVeLA==
X-Amz-Cf-Pop LHR52-C1
X-Cache Error from cloudfront
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-Edge-Origin-Shield-Skipped 0
X-Powered-By Express
```

In particular, the "X-Cache Error from cloudfront" header seems to be of interest - although not really informative enough for me to action anything off of it.